# You can solve this!

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Can you solve this?

1=2
3=18
5=50
4=32
Then
6=?

Answer (score 2):

6 =

> 72

As the sequence is

> 2 times the square of the number

Comment: Bro, it's happening for the second time today with me! Ninjaed me by 10 secs.The earlier one was by 35 secs.

Comment: @Ak19 unlucky dude lol, I think I was just lucky I clicked on it early, wasn’t too hard to work it out after all :P

Comment: Yeah! =)... @BeastlyGerbil

Answer (score 1):

It follows

> $2n^2$ rule.

So,

> $6 = 2\times 36 = 72$